# Issue Sending Values > 127

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstring, bit

After reading the documents about NSString, it seems that NSStrings may be 7 or 8 bits (although judging by the comments, that may be completely wrong). I'm very new to Objective-C and running into some syntax issues. This is my string currently:

`NSString *charles = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

The error that I'm getting is "No known instance method for selector "encoding"". Does anyone know the proper way to convert an `NSString` from 7 bit to 8 bit?

**Update:**

```
unichar value;
    for (value = 0; value < 255; value++)  {
[_device writeToTerminal:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", value]];

}
```

Now, 0-127 print perfectly. The output on the terminal is as expected: 01,02.....A,B,C... ... 1A,1B,1C etc.
But, once I hit above 127 (printed as 7F), I get the value "C2 80" when it should just simply be "80."

Also, I apologize for whatever I did wrong in my question to warrant 3 down votes. Could someone explain what I did wrong so that I can avoid that in the future?

Comment: "It seems that the standard `NSString` is only 7 bit" - WAT?

Comment: `encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` - WAT? You read the documentation?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? What is `i` and what result do you expect?

Comment: They're made of *unichar* characters (2 bytes every character).

Comment: @H2CO3 Am I mistaken that it is only 7 bits? Martin R I'm trying to send 0-255 through a string.

Comment: @OralB: Do you want to store a character with the *character code i* in the string?

Comment: @MartinR Yes I do. I is an unsigned char in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an `NSString` containing one character with a given Unicode in the range 0 .. 0xFFFF
you can either use the `%C` format:

```
unichar c = ...;
NSString *charles = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", c];
```

or use `stringWithCharacters`:

```
unichar c = ...;
NSString *charles = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
```

To get the original character code back:

```
unichar c = [charles characterAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: @OralB: May I ask why you "unaccepted" the answer? Please let me know if there is a problem with it.

Comment: Hey Martin! I implemented your answer but it still appears to be doing the "C2 80" rather than just 80. I updated my question with the code I'm using and the output I'm receiving.

Comment: @OralB: I have no idea what your `writeToTerminal` method does, that makes it very difficult to help :-) And what is `_device`?? - Please try to give complete information about what you do.

Comment: Sure thing! The `writeToTerminal` method is a method from a third party Bluetooth LE library, used to send data to a BLE chip. The method only accepts an `NSString` argument. `_device` is an instance of the class in which I setup all of the BLE information. I hook the device up to a Windows machine, fire up terminal, view the data that I'm sending. It is all working well, except for > 127 values.

Comment: @OralB: But that means that `writeToTerminal` converts the string to UTF-8, and there is nothing you can do about this. You probably have to fix that on the receiving side (convert UTF-8 back to Unicode).

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I will chat with the guy that deals with the receiving end of it then. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You want to grab the C string:

```
NSString *charles = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", i];
[charles UTF8String];
```

Comment: I don't know if the OP really knows what he's asking. However he said he would store a value in [0,255], so it might be correct to use "uc" as format specifier.

Comment: For i > 127 you probably better use the %C format...

Comment: @MartinR Alright thanks man. It still turns to a bunch of C2's and C3's and other weirdness the second it hits 127, but I'll try and figure it out from here since I can't clearly explain it.

Comment: @OralB: UTF-8 uses two or more bytes for all Unicode characters > 128. So if you call `UTF8String` for a string containing a character with the code 0x80 then you get `C2 80`. If that is not what you want then you have to explain your problem better.

Comment: @MartinR Ah okay that makes sense, thank you. Yes I'm trying to avoid the C2 80 and have it just display 80, I have a feeling I need to switch it from UTF8 to 16 bit unicode but am unsure how to.